# Formula for Hamming Distance

Tags: amsmath

I would like to display the following fourmla:

[image]

I tried it like this:

```
\[
\frac{$||(codeA \oplus codeB) \land maskA \land maskB ||$}{$maskA \land maskB$}
\]
```

but the output is wrong

Comment: for error: delete`$` inside formula!

Comment: ...and use \mbox{code} etc to keep code from being emphasized: \[
\frac{||(\mbox{code}A \oplus \mbox{code}B) \land \mbox{mask}A \land \mbox{mask}B ||}{\mbox{mask}A \land \mbox{mask}B}
\]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The formula you want to copy is wrong to begin with, as it uses `\bigotimes` and `\bigcap` where `\otimes` and `\cap` should be employed (a rather common mistake).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\tvar}[1]{\mathrm{#1}} % textual variable
\newcommand{\tsub}[1]{\mathrm{#1}} % textual subscript

\begin{document}

\[
\tvar{HD}_{\tsub{raw}}=
\frac{\lVert (\tvar{codeA}\otimes\tvar{codeB})\cap\tvar{maskA}\cap\tvar{maskB}\rVert}
     {\lVert\tvar{maskA}\cap\tvar{maskB}\rVert}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @4ndro1d The new commands might appear useless, but take as a habit that of defining your macros for repetitive jobs; for instance, `\tvar` and `\tsub` have different semantic values, so they should be distinct commands.

Answer (score 5):

Yet, the "correct" way in terms of markup is (in my opinion):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*\HD{\mathrm{HD}}
\newcommand*\code[1]{\operatorname{code}\mkern-3mu\mathrm{#1}}
\newcommand*\mask[1]{\operatorname{mask}\mkern-3mu\mathrm{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[
  \HD_{\mathrm{raw}} =
    \frac{\lVert(\code{A}\otimes\code{B})\cap\mask{A}\cap\mask{B}\rVert}
         {\lVert\mask{A}\cap\mask{B}\rVert}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4):

Nesting myth environemnts `S....$` in any math environment cause error. Never do this!

For text in equation you can use `\mathrm{...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
\frac{||(\mathrm{codeA} \oplus \mathrm{codeB}) \land \mathrm{maskA} \land \mathrm{maskB} ||}
     {\mathrm{maskA} \land \mathrm{maskB}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:*
As pointed Henri Menke in his comment below, instead `||` is better to use `\|`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathrm{H}_{\mathrm{raw}} = 
\frac{\|(\mathrm{codeA} \oplus \mathrm{codeB}) 
                \land \mathrm{maskA} \land \mathrm{maskB} \|}
     {\mathrm{maskA} \land \mathrm{maskB}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

or even better `\lVert...\rVert` as they are used in other answers. For the recent you need to load package `\amsmath`.

Comment: Please use `\|` instead of `||` or even better `\lVert...\rVert`.

Comment: @HenriMenke, I add example of use `\| ` as you suggested. Actually, I'm aware for this commands, but my first intention was to show OP the cause of error, how to make upright text and left `||` as was in question.

Comment: It is about `\|` being one symbol whereas `||` is two.  Try `\left|| ... \right||` for instance.